# Subtract background from a non-fixed camera footage

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I tried using `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN`to remove the background and highlight humans walking around from a GoPro footage, but the mask generated by the operation was unsubstantial. Here it is -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvCDQ.jpg. Footage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sft1rSykoFo

After some investigation, I found that the camera has to be fixed in place for the method to work.

So how to get foreground (humans) from a non-fixed camera footage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of problem you will need a semantic segmentation algorithm. It will recognise different objects in a scene and label every pixel with the corresponding recognised object.

[image: segmentation example]

There are several options: R-CNN, Mask R-CNN, Yolo, Unet.

If you want to build yourself, I strongly recommend watching Fast.ai videos. If you don't want to build yourself, you can use Google Vision API to get an annotated polyline of objects in an image.